# Manhwa where the female lead is executed by her family and sent back in time by the male lead, who is a wizard

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I read this manhwa a few months ago but forgot its name, where the female lead was executed by her family (I don't remember why) and gets sent back in time by the male lead who is a wizard, but he can't remember why he sent her back.
More detail is that the female lead has black hair and the male lead has yellow hair.

Comment: Where are you likely to have read it?

Comment: Did the female lead have a blonde sister? Was she executed because she wasn't able to learn the family magic, but the sister could?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot that part I think she was also abused of being a fake? Because she couldn't use magic

Answer (score 4):

This is *[I Am the Real One](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-am-the-real-one)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/271112). It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/i-am-the-real-one/info).

> A prophecy foretold that the Grand Duke would only have one water elementalist born from him. Though she lacks her father’s affection, Keira knows she’s destined for those powers. But after years of doing what was right and proper of a noble, **she’s executed after the conniving Cosette appears**, claiming to be the Grand Duke’s real daughter. But then—Keira wakes up with newfound purpose: make changes, allies, and even friends before it’s too late. Will it be enough before Cosette hatches her plot?

Due to a prophecy that her father will only give birth to a single elementalist, the protagonist is assumed to be a fake after her half sister suddenly appears and demonstrates elemental powers. This results in her executed for being a witch, but she wakes up in the past and resolves to change her future.

The scene with the mage is in chapter 32, plus a bit of the end of 31. The blonde magician realizes that she has gone back in time through his magic, but has no idea why his future self did it.

[image: Discussing time travel with no recollection]

Comment: Another match; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266052